# Transpose a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have this tibble:

```
tibble(Cor = c("Linear", "Rank"),
       `a,b` =  c("x1","x2"),
       `b,c` = c("x3","x4")
)
```

I want to transpose it into this tibble:

```
tibble(Cor = c("a,b","b,c"),
       Linear = c("x1","x3"),
       Rank = c("x2","x4")
)
```

Is there a tidyverse simple command to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table::transpose`

```
as_tibble(data.table::transpose(dat, make.names = 'Cor', keep.names = 'Cor'))
 # A tibble: 2 × 3
  Cor   Linear Rank 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 a,b   x1     x2   
2 b,c   x3     x4
```

#### data

```
dat <- tibble(Cor = c("Linear", "Rank"),
       `a,b` =  c("x1","x2"),
       `b,c` = c("x3","x4")
)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can do it in two steps with `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```
df %>%  
  pivot_longer(-Cor) %>%   
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cor, values_from = value)
```

Comment: would this preserve the name of the variable Cor as "Cor"? As much as I hate to mix tidyverse and data.table code, I feel that data.table::transpose is just more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

A faster approach is just using the R base function `t()` after a pipe `%>%`

```
df = tibble(Cor = c("Linear", "Rank"),
       `a,b` =  c("x1","x2"),
       `b,c` = c("x3","x4")
)
df_t = df %>% t()
df_t
    [,1]     [,2]  
Cor "Linear" "Rank"
a,b "x1"     "x2"  
b,c "x3"     "x4"
```